# Managing and organizing the massively increased number of classes after switching to SOLID?

Tags: c#, coding-style, dependency-injection, solid, single-responsibility

Over the last few years, we have been slowly making the switch over to progressively better written code, a few baby steps at a time. We are finally starting to make the switch over to something that at least resembles SOLID, but we're not quite there yet. Since making the switch, one of the biggest complaints from developers is that they can't stand peer reviewing and traversing dozens and dozens of files where previously every task only required the developer touching 5-10 files.

Prior to starting to make the switch, our architecture was organized pretty much like the following (granted, with one or two orders of magnitude more files):

```
Solution
- Business
-- AccountLogic
-- DocumentLogic
-- UsersLogic
- Entities (Database entities)
- Models (Domain Models)
- Repositories
-- AccountRepo
-- DocumentRepo
-- UserRepo
- ViewModels
-- AccountViewModel
-- DocumentViewModel
-- UserViewModel
- UI
```

File wise, everything was incredibly linear and compact. There was obviously a lot of code-duplication, tight-coupling, and headaches, however, everyone could traverse it and figure it out. Complete novices, people who had never so much as opened Visual Studio, could figure it out in just a few weeks. The lack of overall file complexity makes it relatively straightforward for novice developers and new hires to start contributing without too much ramp up time as well. But this is pretty much where any benefits of the code style go out the window.

I wholeheartedly endorse every attempt we make to better our codebase, but it is very common to get some push-back from the rest of the team on massive paradigm shifts like this. A couple of the biggest sticking points currently are:

- Unit Tests
- Class Count
- Peer Review Complexity

Unit tests have been an incredibly hard sell to the team as they all believe they're a waste of time and that they're able to handle-test their code much quicker as a whole than each piece individually. Using unit tests as an endorsement for SOLID has mostly been futile and has mostly become a joke at this point.

Class count is probably the single biggest hurdle to overcome. Tasks that used to take 5-10 files can now take 70-100! While each of these files serve a distinct purpose, the sheer volume of files can be overwhelming. The response from the team has mostly been groans and head scratching. Previously a task may have required one or two repositories, a model or two, a logic layer, and a controller method.

Now, to build a simple file saving application you have a class to check if the file already exists, a class to write the metadata, a class to abstract away `DateTime.Now` so you can inject times for unit testing, interfaces for every file containing logic, files to contain unit tests for each class out there, and one or more files to add everything to your DI container.

For small to medium size applications, SOLID is a super easy sell. Everyone sees the benefit and ease of maintainability. However, they're just not seeing a good value proposition for SOLID on very large scale applications. So I'm trying to find ways to improve organization and management to get us past the growing pains.

---

I figured I'd give a bit stronger of an example of the file volume based on a recently completed task. I was given a task to implement some functionality in one of our newer microservices to receive a file sync request. When the request is received, the service performs a series of lookups and checks, and finally saves the document to a network drive, as well as 2 separate database tables.

To save the document to the network drive, I needed a few specific classes:

```
- IBasePathProvider 
-- string GetBasePath() // returns the network path to store files
-- string GetPatientFolderName() // gets the name of the folder where patient files are stored
- BasePathProvider // provides an implementation of IBasePathProvider
- BasePathProviderTests // ensures we're getting what we expect

- IUniqueFilenameProvider
-- string GetFilename(string path, string fileType);
- UniqueFilenameProvider // performs some filesystem lookups to get a unique filename
- UniqueFilenameProviderTests

- INewGuidProvider // allows me to inject guids to simulate collisions during unit tests
-- Guid NewGuid()
- NewGuidProvider 
- NewGuidProviderTests

- IFileExtensionCombiner // requests may come in a variety of ways, need to ensure extensions are properly appended.
- FileExtensionCombiner
- FileExtensionCombinerTests

- IPatientFileWriter
-- Task SaveFileAsync(string path, byte[] file, string fileType)
-- Task SaveFileAsync(FilePushRequest request) 
- PatientFileWriter
- PatientFileWriterTests
```

So that's a total of 15 classes (excluding POCOs and scaffolding) to perform a fairly straightforward save. This number ballooned significantly when I needed to create POCOs to represent entities in a few systems, built a few repos to communicate with third party systems that are incompatible with our other ORMs, and built logic methods to handle the intricacies of certain operations.

Comment: "Tasks that used to take 5-10 files can now take 70-100! " How in the hell? This is in no way normal. What kind of changes are you making that require changing that many files??

Comment: Well if the SRP is to be followed, each class should have a single responsibility and a single reason to change. Following that, tons of actions that used to be grouped in massive `Logic` files are now broken up into small little units. As you break those parts into classes, interfaces, and write unit tests, you now get dozens of smaller, more targeted classes. Whereas before you had large, very general classes doing hundreds of things each.

Comment: The fact that you have to change *more* files per task (significantly more!) means that you are doing SOLID wrong. The whole point is to organize your code (over time) in a way that reflects the observed change patterns, making the changes simpler. Every principle in SOLID comes with certain reasoning behind it (when and why it should be applied); it looks like you've gotten yourselves in this situation by applying these blindly. Same thing with unit testing (TDD); if you are doing it without having a good grasp on how to do design/architecture, you are going to dig yourself into a hole.

Comment: You've clearly adopted SOLID as a religion rather than a pragmatic tool to help get work done. If something in SOLID is making more work or making things more difficult, **don't do it.**

Comment: @Euphoric: The issue can occur in both ways. I suspect you're responding to the possibility that 70-100 classes is overkill. But it's not impossible that this just happens to be a massive project which was crammed into 5-10 files (I've worked in 20KLOC files before...) and 70-100 is actually the right amount of files.

Comment: @whatsisname: I fully agree with you but want to point out that your statement is liable to be misinterpreted. Very often I hear developers (used to bad practice) argue that SOLID takes more effort; simply because they are only observing the short term (a bit more scaffolding effort) and not the long term (severely reduced maintenance effort). Also, "more difficult" is very subjective, as I've worked with many developers who consider monolithic functions to be clearer as opposed to separate classes or design patterns.

Comment: One thing that works really well for me regarding SRP is to not establish what responsibilities are up-front, but to let new "responsibilities" emerge naturally ("When reading the code in this class, I need to scroll up and down too much, but these 3 methods here are for the same thing that I can move to its own class.")

Comment: Part of me wonders if SOLID is overrated because when you can't easily add features (due to code complexity), then you're overall bug rate could very easy drop (due to fewer features being completed) which could be misinterpreted as "improvement". You'd have to compare pre and post-SOLID velocities to know for sure though. Also, some devs simply prefer procedural, copy-and-pasted codebases, while others prefer SOLID abstractions. Could be just a matter of style preference too.

Comment: @whatsisname I find that SOLID's formulation actually encourages that way of thinking. TDD advocacy often does, too.

Comment: @Graham SOLID isn't new. It's been around for decades and has been proven to be very valuable. Don't be encouraged by stories like this one. SOLID is complicated and difficult to apply. Jumping head first into it, screaming "best practice" isn't a good approach.

Comment: @Graham: the problem isn't that SOLID is over or underrated, it's that there are certain kinds of softwares where it makes sense and others it doesn't. SOLID is best used in beheometh consultingware-ERP type software deployments, the kinds of software the author of SOLID consults for. In software for a vending machine running on a microcontroller, not so much. The SOLID author and many users of it don't always recognize the distinctions.

Comment: @Graham, whereas applying SOLID principles may result in projects consisting of more files, when done correctly it *does not* make it hard to add features.  On the contrary, it tends to facilitate adding features.  The OP's issue of having to modify such large numbers of files to apply a change is thoroughly inconsistent with SOLID -- they seem to have misunderstood the relevant design principles.

Comment: @JohnBollinger in my case I wasn't necessarily having to modify many files to add functionality, but rather I was having to create many files as none of prerequisite functionality existed for what I was building. If we wanted to modify some portion of the implemented functionality, in theory each change should only require me to touch 1 or 2 files now.

Comment: Related: [When using the Single Responsibility Principle, what constitutes a “responsibility?”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/345018/234437)

Comment: Looks like your classes and other elements are too granular; you are being concerned with each individual operation, and you are not thinking about domain concepts and not modeling the domain. Your tests also seem to depend on the internals, but they should really be expressed in terms of higher level policies (so you can refactor without breaking half of the tests). It also looks like you are testing stuff that you really shouldn't: e.g., what does  `NewGuidProviderTests` test for? If `System.Guid.NewGuid()` returns a GUID?

Comment: There's a disorder of thought I call "object happiness disease", which is the belief that OO techniques are an end in themselves, rather than just one of many possible techniques to decrease the costs of working in a large codebase. You have a particularly advanced form, "SOLID happiness disease". SOLID isn't the goal. Lowering the cost of maintaining the codebase is the goal. Evaluate your proposals in that context, not in whether it is doctrinaire SOLID. (That your proposals are also probably not actually doctrinaire SOLID is also a good point to consider.)

Comment: @sbecker As for it being "proven to be very valuable" I'm sure it has on LOTS of projects (I've even written some!) but its not a silver bullet for ALL projects (as whatsisname indicates). Assuming that "SOLID = Better than not-SOLID" is the problem. Its just a technique (certainly a good one), but not a cure-all.

Comment: HIGHLY related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14856/what-popular-best-practices-are-not-always-best-and-why/38504#38504

Comment: Again, I must ask where the line is drawn. Following SOLID, one of the most intuitive things for me personally is setting up DI so that pretty much none of my classes have dependencies on any other classes. I'm able to achieve 100% code coverage with arguably pretty decent tests in most cases. As you start to combine class responsibilities, the number of dependencies and resources those classes require also increases. How do you combat having to inject potentially 10-15 classes into the class when you have operations that are largely cross-cutting.

Comment: @JDDavis: knowing where to draw that line is part of the craft of software development. We can't do your job for you. If you nor your coworkers have the experience to have a 6th sense about it, you're just going to have to take your best shot and see how it goes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBxcalnSzIk

Comment: @Graham "_Part of me wonders if SOLID is overrated_" even more, IMHO, the O is anachronistic. Most classes I write are supposed to do the one thing I think of, and not the infinite other things other people could think of when subclassing it. Most classes I write, I write with a "not open" mindset and they are better off as final/sealed.

Comment: It reminds me of https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition.

Comment: I wish it were idiomatic, in more languages, to put multiple small and related classes (as well as free functions/classes with a single static method and no state) into a single file, at ~50-200 lines per file.  I've found that that style makes SOLID a good bit easier.

Comment: Seriously, (assuming you're using proper version control), **revert to the version before you started this mess**, then burn a copy of the branch that went wrong to a CD (or maybe a blu-ray, since it sounds like it no longer fits on a CD or even a DVD) and find someone with the right spiritial empowerments to exorcise it in fire.

Comment: Maybe this question I asked a while ago is also very relevant: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220230/what-is-the-real-responsibility-of-a-class

Comment: @R.Schmitz: The O in SOLID is not necessarily about subclassing (in fact, it uses the term "software entities"). There's nuance to it; despite how it appears in its condensed statement, it doesn't say that it should be applied everywhere equally. And it's not anachronistic at all, we all rely on it every day. It can be applied at many levels: encapsulation, subclassing, interface implementation, dependency inversion, plugin architectures, protocols, APIs, etc. are all different expressions of OCP. Anything that relies on something else needs that something to be relatively unchanging (closed).

Comment: Remember that from the point of view of design, ***a function is an object***, and a function signature is an interface. You don't need to implement a million classes each with one function in order to be doing SOLID.

Answer (score 105):

> Now, to build a simple file saving application you have a class to check if the file already exists, a class to write the metadata, a class to abstract away DateTime.Now so you can inject times for unit testing, interfaces for every file containing logic, files to contain unit tests for each class out there, and one or more files to add everything to your DI container.

I think you have misunderstood the idea of a single responsibility. A class's single responsibility might be "save a file". To do that, it then may break that responsibility down into a method that checks whether a file exists, a method that writes metadata etc. Each those methods then has a single responsibility, which is part of the class's overall responsibility.

A class to abstract away `DateTime.Now` sounds good. But you only need one of those and it could be wrapped up with other environment features into a single class with the responsibility for abstracting environmental features. Again a single responsibility with multiple sub-responsibilities.

You do not need "interfaces for every file containing logic", you need interfaces for classes that have side-effects, e.g. those classes that read/write to files or databases; and even then, they are only needed for the public parts of that functionality. So for example in `AccountRepo`, you might not need any interfaces, you might only need an interface for the actual database access which is injected into that repo.

> Unit tests have been an incredibly hard sell to the team as they all believe they're a waste of time and that they're able to handle-test their code much quicker as a whole than each piece individually. Using unit tests as an endorsement for SOLID has mostly been futile and has mostly become a joke at this point.

This suggests that you have misunderstood unit tests too. The "unit" of a unit test is not a unit of code. What even is a unit of code? A class? A method? A variable? A single machine instruction? No, the "unit" refers to a unit of isolation, i.e. code that can execute in isolation from other parts of the code. A simple test of whether an automated test is a unit test or not is whether you can run it in parallel with all your other unit tests without affecting its result. There's a couple more rules of thumb around unit tests, but that is your key measure.

So if parts of your code can indeed be tested as a whole without affecting other parts, then do that.

Always be pragmatic and remember everything is a compromise. The more you adhere to DRY, the more tightly coupled you code must become. The more you introduce abstractions, the easier the code is to test, but the harder it is to understand. Avoid ideology and find a good balance between the ideal and keeping it simple. There lies the sweet spot of maximum efficiency both for development and maintenance.

Comment: I'd like to add that a similar headache arises when people try to adhere to the too oft repeated mantra of "methods should only do one thing" and end up with tons of one line methods just because it can technically be made into a method.

Comment: Re *"Always be pragmatic and remember everything is a compromise"*: Uncle Bob's disciples are not known for this (no matter the original intent).

Comment: Related: *[DevTernity 2017: Ian Cooper - TDD, Where Did It All Go Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM&t=24m05s)* at 24 min 05 secs, ***"Test behaviours (not implementation details)"***. (Though the microphone scratching can be ... challenging. Best consumed 5 minutes at a time, with several hours, or even days, of rest in between...)

Comment: _"A class's single responsibility might be 'save a file'"_ - No, this is exactly the problem.  Saving should be a method on a `File` class, not its own `FileSaver` class.  Both agile shops I worked at did it the `FileSaver` way, and they both had OP's issue of having way _waaay_ too many classes.  Honestly the SRP needs to be rewritten as _"each method has only one reason to change"_, rather than _"each class.."_

Comment: To sum the first part up, you usually have a coffee intern, not a full suite of plug-in-percolator, flip-switch, check-if-sugar-needs-refilling, open-fridge, get-out-milk, get-out-spoons, get-down-cups, pour-coffee, add-sugar, add-milk, stir-cup, and deliver-cup interns. ;P

Comment: The root cause of the OP's problem seem to be misunderstanding the difference between functions which should perform a single *task,* and a classes which should have a single *responsibility.*

Comment: @alephzero, hmm, I'd never thought of it in those words before, but you capture things perfectly. I'm going to steal that phrase for future use. Thanks :)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Oh yes, the good old Java "verbs are evil" approach. It's funny how in some ways, we've come the full circle - classes with a single "Execute" method are eerily similar to bare functions (though without many of the benefits functions have in real FP).

Comment: *"Rules are for the guidance of wise men and the obedience of fools."* - Douglas Bader

Comment: @Logarr And then there are people who have 1000 methods of 1 line in order to really just do one thing :) `int IncrementCounter(int i) => i + 1;`. The SRP does not define what "one thing" is. It's good as inspiration, not usable as a rule.

Answer (score 30):

> Tasks that used to take 5-10 files can now take 70-100!

This is the *opposite* of the single-responsibility principle (SRP).  To get to that point, you must have divided up your functionality in a very fine-grained way, but that's not what the SRP is about -- doing that ignores the key idea of *cohesiveness*.

According to the SRP, software should be divided into modules along lines defined by their possible reasons to change, so that a single design change can be applied in *just one* module without requiring modifications elsewhere.  A single "module" in this sense may correspond to more than one class, but if one change requires you to touch tens of files then either it's really multiple changes or you're doing SRP wrong.

Bob Martin, who originally formulated the SRP, wrote [a blog post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) a few years ago to try to clarify the situation.  It discusses at some length what a "reason to change" is for the purposes of the SRP.  It's worth a read in its entirety, but among the things within deserving special attention is this alternative wording of the SRP:

> **Gather together the things that change for the same reasons**. Separate
>   those things that change for different reasons.

(emphasis mine).  The SRP is *not* about splitting things up into the tiniest possible pieces.  That's not good design, and your team is right to resist.  It makes your code base harder to update and to maintain.  It sounds like you may be trying to sell your team on it based on unit testing considerations, but that would be putting the cart before the horse.

Similarly, the interface segregation principle should not be taken as an absolute.  It is no more a reason to divide your code so finely than is the SRP, and it generally aligns pretty well with the SRP.  That an interface contains *some* methods that *some* clients do not use is not a reason to break it up.  You are again looking for cohesion.

Additionally, I urge you not to take the open-closed principle or the Liskov substitution principle as a reason to favor deep inheritance hierarchies.  There is no tighter coupling than a subclass with its superclasses, and tight coupling is a design problem.  Instead, favor composition over inheritance wherever it makes sense to do so.  This will reduce your coupling, and thus the number of files a particular change may need to touch, and it aligns nicely with dependency inversion.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to figure out where the line is. In a recent task, I had to perform a fairly simple operation, but it was in a codebase without much existing scaffolding or functionality. As such, everything I needed to do was very simple, but all pretty unique and didn't seem to fit in shared classes. In my case, I needed to save a document to a network drive, and log it to two separate database tables. The rules surrounding each step were fairly particular. Even the filename generation (a simple guid) had a few classes to make testing more convenient.

Comment: Again, @JDDavis, choosing multiple classes over a single one purely for testability purposes is putting the cart before the horse, and it goes directly against the SRP, which calls for grouping cohesive functionalities together.  I can't advise you on particulars, but the problem that individual functional changes require modifying many files is an issue that you should be addressing (and attempting to avoid), not one that you should be trying to justify.

Comment: Agreeing, I add this. To quote Wikipedia, "Martin defines a responsibility as a reason to change, and concludes that a class or module should have one, and only one, reason to be changed (i.e. rewritten)." and "he more recently stated "This principle is about people."" In fact, I believe this means that the "responsibility" in SRP refers to stakeholders, not functionality. A class should be responsible for changes required by only one stakeholder (person requiring that you change your program), so that you change as FEW things as possible in response to different stakeholders demanding change.

Answer (score 14):

> Tasks that used to take 5-10 files can now take 70-100!

This is a lie. The tasks never took only 5-10 files.

You are not solving any tasks with less than 10 files. Why? Because you're using C#. C# is a high level language. You are using more than 10 files just to create hello world.

Oh sure you don't notice them because you didn't write them. So you don't look in them. You trust them.

The problem isn't the number of files. It's that you now have so much going on that you don't trust.

So figure out how to make those tests work to the point that once they pass you trust these files the way you trust the files in .NET. Doing that is the point of unit testing. No one cares about the number of files. They care about the number of things they can't trust.

> For small to medium size applications, SOLID is a super easy sell. Everyone sees the benefit and ease of maintainability. However, they're just not seeing a good value proposition for SOLID on very large scale applications.

Change is hard on very large scale applications no mater what you do. The best wisdom to apply here doesn't come from Uncle Bob. It comes from Michael Feathers in his book Working Effectively with Legacy Code.

Do not start a rewrite fest. The old code represents hard won knowledge. Tossing it out because it has problems and isn't expressed in new and improved paradigm X is just asking for a new set of problems and no hard won knowledge.

Instead find ways to make testable your old untestable code (legacy code in Feathers speak). In this metaphor code is like a shirt. Large parts are joined at natural seams that can be undone to separate the code the way you'd remove the seams. Do this to allow you to attach test "sleeves" that let you isolate the rest of the code. Now when you create the test sleeves you have confidence in the sleeves because you did this with a working shirt. (ow, this metaphor is starting to hurt).

This idea flows from the assumption that, like in most shops, the only up to date requirements are in the working code. This lets you lock that down in tests that allow you to make changes to the proven working code without it losing every bit of it's proven working status. Now with this first wave of tests in place you can start making changes that make the "legacy" (untestable) code testable. You can be bold because the seams tests are backing you up by saying this is what it always did and the new tests show that your code actually does what you think it does.

What does any of this have to do with:

> Managing and organizing the massively increased number of classes after switching to SOLID?

Abstraction.

You can make me hate any code base with bad abstractions. A bad abstraction is something that makes me look inside. Don't surprise me when I look inside. Be pretty much what I expected.

Give me a good name, readable tests (examples) that show how to use the interface, and organize it so I can find things and I wont care if we used 10, 100, or 1000 files.

You help me find things with good descriptive names. Put things with good names in things with good names.

If you do all this right, you will abstract the files to where finishing a task has you only depending on 3 to 5 other files. The 70-100 files are still there. But they're hiding behind the 3 to 5. That only works if you trust the 3 to 5 to do that right.

So what you really need is the vocabulary to come up with good names for all these things and tests that people trust so they'll stop wading through everything. Without that you'd be making me crazy too.

@Delioth [makes a good point](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/394399/managing-and-organizing-the-massively-increased-number-of-classes-after-switchin/394449?noredirect=1#comment868690_394449)  about growing pains. When you're used to the dishes being in the cupboard above the dish washer it takes some getting used to them being above the breakfast bar. Makes some things harder. Makes some things easier. But it causes all kinds of nightmares if people don't agree where the dishes go. In a large code base the problem is you can only move some of the dishes at a time. So now you have dishes in two places. It's confusing. Makes it hard to trust that the dishes are where they're supposed to be. If you want to get past this though the only thing to do is keep moving the dishes.

The problem with that is you'd really like to know if having the dishes over the breakfast bar is worth it before going through all this nonsense. Well for that all I can recommend is go camping.

When trying out a new paradigm for the first time the last place you should be applying it is in a large code base. This goes for every member of the team. No one should be taking it on faith that SOLID works, that OOP works, or that functional programming works. Every team member should get a chance to play with the new idea, whatever it is, in a toy project. It lets them see at least how it works. It lets them see what it doesn't do well. It lets them learn to do it right before they make a big mess.

Giving people a safe place to play will help them adopt new ideas and give them confidence that the dishes really could work in their new home.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that some of the question's pain is likely just growing pain as well - while, yes, they might need to make 15 files for this one thing... now they never have to write a GUIDProvider again, or a BasePathProvider, or an ExtensionProvider, etc. It's the same sort of hurdle you get when you start a new greenfield project - bunches of supporting features that are mostly trivial, stupid to write, and yet still need to be written. Sucks to build them, but once they're there you shouldn't need to think about them.... ever.

Comment: @Delioth I'm incredibly inclined to believe this is the case. Previously, if we needed some subset of functionality (lets say we simply wanted a URL housed in AppSettings), we simply had one massive class that was passed around and used. With the new approach, there's no reason to pass around the entirety of `AppSettings` just to get a url or file path.

Comment: ***Do not start a rewrite fest. The old code represents hard won knowledge. Tossing it out because it has problems and isn't expressed in new and improved paradigm X is just asking for a new set of problems and no hard won knowledge.*** This. Absolutely.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds as though your code isn't very well decoupled and/or your task sizes are way too big.

Code changes *should* be 5-10 files unless you're doing a codemod or large scale refactoring. If a single change touches a lot of files, it probably means that your changes cascade. Some improved abstractions (more single responsibility, interface segregation, dependency inversion) should help. It's also possible you maybe went *too* single responsibility and could use a bit more pragmatism - shorter and thinner type hierarchies. That should make the code easier to understand too since you don't have to understand dozens of files to know what the code is doing.

It also might be a sign that your work is too big. Instead of "hey, add this feature" (which requires UI changes and api changes and data access changes and security changes and test changes and...) break it down into more serviceable chunks. That becomes easier to review and easier to understand because it requires you to set up decent contracts between the bits.

And of course, unit tests help all of this. They force you to make decent interfaces. They force you to make your code flexible enough to inject the bits needed to test (if it's hard to test, it'll be hard to reuse). And they push people away from over-engineering stuff because the more you engineer the more you need to test.

Comment: The 5-10 files to 70-100 files is a bit more than a hypothetical. My last task was to create some functionality in one of our newer microservices. The new service was supposed to receive a request, and save a document. In doing so, I needed classes to represent the user entities in 2 separate databases and repos for each. Repos to represent other tables I needed to write to. Dedicated classes to handle file-data checking and name-generation. And the list goes on. Not to mention, every class that contained logic was represented by an interface so it could be mocked up for unit tests.

Comment: As far as our older codebases, they are all tightly coupled and incredibly monolithic. With the SOLID approach, the only coupling between classes has been in the case of POCOs, everything else is passed through DI and interfaces.

Comment: @JDDavis - wait, why is one microservice working directly with multiple databases?

Comment: It was a compromise with our dev manager. He massively prefers monolithic and procedural software. As such, our microservices are a lot more macro than they should be. As our infrastructure gets better, slowly things will move into their own microservices. For now we're somewhat following the strangler approach to move certain functionality out into microservices. As multiple services need access to a specific resource, we are moving those into their own microservices as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to expound on some of the things already mentioned here, but more from a perspective of where object boundaries are drawn.  If you're following something akin to Domain-Driven Design, then your objects are probably going to represent aspects of your business.  `Customer` and `Order`, for example, would be objects.  Now, if I were to make a guess based on the class names that you had as your starting point, your `AccountLogic` class had code that would run for *any* account.  In OO, however, each class is meant to have context and identity.  You should not get an `Account` object and then pass it into an `AccountLogic` class and have that class make changes to the `Account` object.  That is what is called an anemic model, and doesn't represent OO very well.  Instead, your `Account` class should have behavior, such as `Account.Close()` or `Account.UpdateEmail()`, and those behaviors would affect only that instance of the account.

Now, HOW these behaviors are handled can (and in a lot of cases should) be off-loaded to dependencies represented by abstractions (ie, interfaces).  `Account.UpdateEmail`, for example, might want to update a database, or a file, or send a message to a service bus, etc.  And that might change in the future.  So your `Account` class may have a dependency on, for example, an `IEmailUpdate`, which could be one of many interfaces implemented by an `AccountRepository` object.  You wouldn't want to pass a whole `IAccountRepository` interface to the `Account` object because it would probably do too much, such as search and find other (any) accounts, which you may not want the `Account` object to have access to, but even though `AccountRepository` might implement both `IAccountRepository` and `IEmailUpdate` interfaces, the `Account` object would only have access to the small portions that it needs.  This helps you maintain the **Interface Segregation Principle**.

Realistically, as other people have mentioned, if you're dealing with an explosion of classes, chances are that you're using SOLID principle (and, by extension, OO) the wrong way.  SOLID should be helping you simplify your code, not complicate it.  But it takes time to really understand what things like the SRP mean.  The more important thing, though, is that how SOLID works is going to be very dependent on your domain and bounded contexts (another DDD term).  There's no silver bullet or one-size-fits-all.

One more thing that I like to emphasize to people I work with: again, an OOP object should have behavior, and is, in fact, defined by its behavior, not its data.  If your object has nothing but properties and fields, it still has behavior, though probably not the behavior you intended.  A publicly-writable/settable property with no other set logic implies that the behavior for its containing class is that anyone anywhere for whatever reason and at any time is allowed to modify the value of that property without any necessary business logic or validation in between.  That's not usually the behavior people intend, but if you have an anemic model, that's generally the behavior your classes are announcing to anyone using them.

Answer (score 2):

> So that's a total of 15 classes (excluding POCOs and scaffolding) to perform a fairly straightforward save.

That's crazy.... but these classes sound like something I'd write myself. So let's have a look at them. Let's ignore the interfaces and tests for now.

- `BasePathProvider` - IMHO any non-trivial project working with files needs it. So I'd assume, there's already such a thing and you can use it as is.
- `UniqueFilenameProvider` - Sure, you have it already, haven't you?
- `NewGuidProvider` - The same case, unless you're just staring to use GUID.
- `FileExtensionCombiner` - The same case.
- `PatientFileWriter` - I guess, this is the main class for the current task.

To me, it looks good: You need to write one new class which needs four helper classes. All four helper classes sound pretty reusable, so I'd bet they're already somewhere in you code base. Otherwise, it's either bad luck (are you really the person in your team to write files and use GUIDs???) or some other problem.

---

Concerning the test classes, sure, when you create a new class, or update it, it should be tested. So writing five classes means writing five test classes, too. But this doesn't make the design any more complicated:

- You won't ever use the test classes elsewhere as they will get executed automatically and that's all.
- You want ever look at them again, unless you update the classes under test or unless you use them as documentation (ideally, the tests show clearly how a class is supposed to be used).

---

Concerning the interfaces, they're only needed when either your DI framework or your testing framework can't deal with classes. You may see them as a toll for imperfect tools. Or you may see them as a useful abstraction allowing you to forget that there are more complicated things - reading the source of an interface takes much less time than reading the source of its implementation.

Comment: I'm thankful for this point of view. In this specific case, I was writing functionality into a fairly new microservice. Unfortunately, even in our main codebase, while we do have some of the above in use, none of it is really in a remotely reusable way. Everything that needs to be reusable ended up in some static class or it's just copy and pasted around the code. I do think I've still been going a bit far, but I do agree that not *everything* needs to be completely dissected and decoupled.

Comment: @JDDavis I was trying to write something different from the other answers (which I mostly agree with). Whenever you copy&paste something, you're preventing reuse as instead of generalizing something you create another non-reusable piece of code, which will force you to copy&paste more one day. IMHO it's the second biggest sin, just after blindly following rules. You need to find your sweet spot, where following rules makes you more productive (especially w.r.t. the future changes) and occasionally breaking them a bit helps in cases when the effort wouldn't be inappropriate. It's all relative.

Comment: @JDDavis And everything depends on the quality of your tools. Example: There are people claiming that DI is enterprisey and complicated, while I'm claiming that [it's mostly free](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/245091/14167). `+++` Concerning breaking the rules: There are four classes, I need in places, where I could only inject them after a major refactoring making the code more ugly (at least for my eyes), so I decided to make them to singletons (a better programmer might find a better way, but I'm happy with it; the number of these singletons haven't changes since ages).

Comment: This answer expresses pretty much what I was thinking when the OP added the example to the question. @JDDavis  Let me add that you may save some boilerplate code/classes by using functional tools for the simple cases. A a GUI provider, for example - instead of introcuding a new interface a new class for this, why not just utilize `Func<Guid>` for this, and inject a anonymous method like `()=>Guid.NewGuid()` into the constructor? And there is no need to test this .Net framework function, this is something Microsoft has done for you. In total, this will save you 4 classes.

Comment: ... and you should check if the other cases you presented can be simplified the same way (probably not all of them).

Comment: @DocBrown I'll be honest, I didn't know that was possible with .Net Core's DI container.

Comment: @JDDavis: I don't know either if that is possible with the DI container you are using, but it is definitely possible when you use [pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). So your "massively increased number of classes" is probably not caused by "SOLID", but by introducing a DI container? Then your whole question is maybe based on the misunderstanding that SOLID implies the usage of such a container?

Comment: @DocBrown I'm using the [default .Net Core DI Container](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2), and after some research, it looks like it's very much possible to pass in `Func<T>` objects. So I'll definitely explore it as a route in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on abstractions, creating single-responsibility classes, and writing unit tests are not exact sciences. It's perfectly normal to swing too far in one direction when learning, go to an extreme, and then find a norm that makes sense. It just sounds like your pendulum has swung too far, and might even be stuck.

Here's where I suspect this is going off the rails:

> Unit tests have been an incredibly hard sell to the team as they all believe they're a waste of time and that they're able to handle-test their code much quicker as a whole than each piece individually. Using unit tests as an endorsement for SOLID has mostly been futile and has mostly become a joke at this point.

One of the benefits that comes from most SOLID principles (certainly not the only benefit) is that it makes writing unit tests for our code easier. If a class depends on an abstractions we can mock the abstractions. Abstractions which are segregated are easier to mock. If a class does one thing it's likely to have lower complexity, which means it's easier to know and test all of its possible paths.

If your team isn't writing unit tests, two related things are happening:

First, they are doing a lot of extra work to create all of these interfaces and classes without realizing the full benefits. It takes a little time and practice to see how writing unit tests makes our lives easier. There are reasons why people who learn to write unit tests stick to it, but you have to persist long enough to discover them for yourself. If your team isn't attempting that then they're going to feel like the rest of the extra work they're doing is useless.

For example, what happens when they need to refactor? If they've got a hundred little classes but no tests to tell them whether or not their changes will work, those extra classes and interfaces are going to seem like a burden, not an improvement.

Second, writing unit tests can help you to understand how much abstraction your code really needs. Like I said, it's not a science. We start off badly, veering all over the place, and get better. Unit tests have a peculiar way of complementing SOLID. How do you know when you need to add an abstraction or break something apart? In other words, how do you know when you're "SOLID enough?" Often the answer is when you can't test something.

Maybe your code would be testable without creating as many tiny abstractions and classes. But if you're not writing the tests, how can you tell? How far do we go? We can become obsessed with breaking things up smaller and smaller. It's a rabbit hole. The ability to write tests for our code helps us see when we've accomplished our purpose so that we can stop obsessing, move on, and have fun writing more code.

Unit tests aren't a silver bullet that solves everything, but they are a really awesome bullet that makes developers' lives better. We're not perfect, and neither are our tests. But tests give us confidence. We expect our code to be right and we're surprised when it's wrong, not the other way around. We're not perfect and neither are our tests. But when our code is tested we have confidence. We're less likely to bite our nails when our code is deployed and wonder what's going to break this time and whether it's going to be our fault.

On top of that, once we get the hang of it, writing unit tests makes developing code faster, not slower. We spend less time revisiting old code or debugging to find problems that are like needles in a haystack.

Bugs decrease, we get more done, and we replace anxiety with confidence. It's not a fad or snake oil. It's real. Many developers will attest to this. If your team hasn't experienced this, they need to push through that learning curve and get over the hump. Give it a chance, realizing that they won't get results instantly. But when it happens they'll be glad they did and they'll never look back. (Or they'll become isolated pariahs and write angry blog posts about how unit tests and most other accumulated programming knowledge is a waste of time.)

> Since making the switch, one of the biggest complaints from developers is that they can't stand peer reviewing and traversing dozens and dozens of files where previously every task only required the developer touching 5-10 files.

Peer review is a lot easier when all of the unit tests pass and a big part of that review is just making sure that the tests are meaningful.